# Installing phonegap app to android emulator using windows CLI

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova, installation

I'm trying to install my Phonegap application onto an Android AVD/Emulator.  I have launched the AVD and it's registering as 5554:Nexus_S.

When using the Phonegap commands at the Windows prompt I am typing:

```
phonegap build android
phonegap install android
```

The output I get says it successfully installed the app onto the device, but it never shows up.  This is the output of the install command:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\username\app\platforms\android\assets\www\phonegap.js
[phonegap] successfully installed onto device
```

I've tried variations of targeting the device using options with no luck:

```
--device=5554
--target=5554
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also getting this weird thing now, until morning everything was fine, but now I am unable to see the app on the device. Although, I too get the `successfully installed onto device` msg. I am running it on a physical device.

Comment: One thing I now notice is the compilation process is now sped up. Earlier _(when the app was installing onto the device [with no problems])_, the overall time taken by the `phonegap run android` command was about 1-2 minutes, but now _(when the app doesn't install but shows`successfully installed`)_, it takes hardly 30 seconds. **Something fishy is going around**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out.  You have to specify the --emulator= in the call, so the command looks like:

```
phonegap install --emulator=emulator-5554 android
```

You can find the name/id of your running emulators by running the `list-started-emulators.bat` under the `/platforms/android/cordova/lib/` folder in your project.

Comment: i ran start-emulator.bat it started the emulator but when list-started-emulators.bat is run, No started emulator. Actually, the first batch file is showing, Waiting for emulator. How much time will it take? I tried a whole to get this to work, please help.

Comment: I have tried variations of all the solutions posted here but still cannot see the app on the emulator.

Comment: _phonegap run android -e=emulator-5554_ worked for me, but _phonegap run android -emulator=emulator-5554_ did not. (Using Phonegap version 5.5.2)

Answer (score 2):

Another quick note is that sometimes even when you have started the emulator phonegap will not recognize it... so you have to start it from phonegap bat file so that the right process number is registered. to do this. 
Use the following command,
1. List-emulator-images.bat : This will display available emulator images you have 
2. start-emulator  : This will start the emulator which will register with phonegap.

Also make sure you are running all of this from and ADMIN Enabled command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've solved my problem. This solution may not be applied to all, but I was suffering from the same problem as I've mentioned in the comments of the question.

What did I do wrong?

I made some changes in one of the plugins.
I was working on my app and added the Vibration plugin. I made some changes in the plugin, both in the generic version [`your_project_root\plugins\org.apache.cordova.vibration\src\android\Vibration.java`] and also in the platform specific version [`your_project_root\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\vibration\Vibration.java`].

But when I reverted the changes back, everything went fine.

I say it again, this solution may not be generic but can be useful for at least my type of problem.

And this gives rise to another question, can't we make changes in the Plugins?
I think it is totally fine to make changes in them. Maybe I had done something wrong.